# How do I add a custom HtmlHelper to my NopCommerce template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, templates, nopcommerce

NopCommerce templates typically include just views and assets, not code. *But can they?*

I'd like to have a custom HtmlHelper that I refer to from my views. For example, if I create this extension in my theme:

```
namespace Nop.Theme.Foo.Helpers
{
    public static class NopHelpers
    {
        public static string Test(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            return "foo";
        }
    }
}
```

Where do I put the built dll? And how do I refer to it in my view? The following does *not* work:

```
@using Nop.Theme.Foo.Helpers;
...
@Html.Test()
```

The error is: `error: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Theme' does not exist in the namespace 'Nop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.

So I guess my questions are:

1. how do I add the custom helper to my theme/template?
2. where does the build output go (so NopCommerce can load it)?
3. how do I refer to the helper from my view?

Answer (score 3):

Any dlls in the theme folder *will be ignored*. You can still build them in your theme project, but you'll need to *drop them into the `Nop.Web/bin` folder* so they get loaded.

So:

#### how do I add the custom helper to my theme/template?

Just like you have it--create an extenstion method against `HtmlHelper` directly in your theme project.

#### where does the build output go (so NopCommerce can load it)?

Move the theme dll to `Nop.Web/bin`--i.e. the `bin` directory at the root of your website.

#### how do I refer to the helper from my view?

Just like you have it. Add a using statement, and then use the helper:

```
@using Nop.Theme.Foo.Helpers;
...
@Html.Test()
```

---

Oh, and if you want to resolve an instance of something inside your static helper, you can use this:

```
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
// ...
var whateverYouWant = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWhateverYouWant>();
```

Comment: +1 for adding the namespace `@using Nop.Theme.Foo.Helpers;`. This will highlight the function u needed in your custom Helpers(static class)